# Divide image into rectangles information in Python

Tags: python, image, algorithm, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a series of images that are nothing more than a series of colored rectangles in a black background 
Example:[image]. How could I (using PIL in Python 3.7) make a program that would identify these rectangles (xy position, color and size)? Efficiency is not really important, so nested `for`s are acceptable. Every algorithm I've been able to come up with until now have a lot of flaws and can go wrong in many different ways, or are just WAY too complex and not at all worth it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write any code at all, you can do that with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

Just in the Terminal (Command Prompt on Windows), you can run:

```
magick convert image.png                            \
   -define connected-components:verbose=true        \
   -define connected-components:area-threshold=100  \
   -connected-components 4 -auto-level output.png
```

**Sample Output**

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 1200x714+0+0 651.2,369.3 703177 srgb(0,0,0)
  164: 1200x86+0+714 599.5,756.5 103200 srgb(255,21,0)
  2: 363x155+80+60 261.0,137.0 56265 srgb(255,255,255)
  26: 127x323+60+302 122.6,463.2 39668 srgb(255,255,255)
  54: 308x109+352+373 505.5,427.0 33572 srgb(255,255,255)
  1: 102x159+641+47 691.5,126.0 16218 srgb(255,255,255)
  53: 79x100+977+371 1016.0,420.5 7900 srgb(0,17,255)
```

So, looking at the line starting `0:` there is a rectangle measuring 1200x714 starting at 0,0 (top-left corner) with colour black, i.e. srgb(0,0,0).

Looking at the next line, there is a rectangle measuring 1200x86 starting 714 pixels down from the top-left corner with colour red, i.e. srgb(255,21,0).

And so on.

The last line is a rectangle 79x100 positioned at [977,31] with colour blue, i.e. srgb(0,17,255).

Comment: Well, I would rather have the code print out the UI line directly (something like "button = Button(340, 100, 20, 30, 'Ex. case')"), but thinking about it, since I can (and know how to) run os commands on python, get and parse the output, this is really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I Don't know how far you are OK with OpenCV .

If your ready to use openCV , you can use the findContours to get the desired things .

Below is the code:

```
    import cv2
    readImage= cv2.imread(r"<ImagePath>\oKvDi.png")
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #Code to Find edges of Square using Canny edge detection method and finding Contours and drawing in Back Line

    edges = cv2.Canny(img_gray, 0, 100)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    #Just for your reference to show all rectangles are found
    cv2.drawContours(readImage, contours, -1, (0, 0, 0), 5)
    cv2.imwrite(r"<ImageSavePath>/a.png",readImage)
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks, I have no problem with using OpenCV, just said PIL in the question because I have a better idea of what I'm doing, so how can I get the data about the rectangles? again, I'm pretty much of a newbie in OpenCV. If I got it right `contours` are the key, but I have little to no idea what do do from here

Comment: As you have only rectangles in image , you just print `contours` to know the co-ordinates

Comment: Well, after using `print(contours)` in another image with just 1 rectangle, I have this: http://prntscr.com/n1g2md , and there is the problem, I have no idea how to process all this data. It seems to be split in groups of 7, which is really confusing me

Comment: @Locked What actually your are trying to do with that co-ordinate?

Comment: Just to have the top-left co-ordinates and size of the rectangles on the image, and print them, for a UI i'm making, and I don't want to have to re-check every time I change an element's position or size, so I'd just make the UI in a image-editing software, put it into this program, and it would output all I need to know to get the UI the way I want it